# Create SignedPayload from own vector

Tags: substrate

Is there a way to create `SignedPayload` from a vector from `signed_payload.encode()` in rust, trait impl [here](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/master/sp_runtime/generic/struct.SignedPayload.html#implementations), similar to the `createType` method in polkadotJS.

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, you want the opposite of `signed_payload.encode()`? So bytes to a `SignedPayload` object?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi, yes, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: The general solution to this is to use `decode`, so it would be something like `SignedPayload::decode(&mut &raw_bytes[..]).unwrap_or_default()`, but it does not appear that `SignedPayload` implements encode or decode, so I don't think this is possible in general. You might be able to create your own decoder function, but it feels pretty hacky. What is your scenario?

Comment: The scenario is to have the encoded bytes for signing and then  to _decode_ it to `SignedPayload` object, where I can `.deconstruct` it and create `UncheckedExtrinsic`.